# Optimize mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am connecting to a mysql db with mysql-connector in python. In the normal run of events, I won't have to process more than 1000 rows but occasionally I might need to process 20k plus rows of data and that is where my query gets very slow and times out. I have tried using an iterator in mysql-connector so as to limit the amount I process at a given time but it seems this is only implemented for MySQLdb in py.

```
SELECT
        ROUND(311.30004 - (20.110938 * temp.value) 
        - (2.012626 * hum.value) - (2.006346 * airspeed.value) 
        + (0.4059 * POWER(temp.value, 2) + (0.006604 * POWER(hum.value, 2)) 
        + (3.151145 * POWER(airspeed.value, 2) + (0.05555 * temp.value * hum.value) 
        - (0.37037 * temp.value * airspeed.value) + (0.03968 * hum.value * airspeed.value))), 2) 
        AS value, temp.time, temp.x, temp.y, temp.z, temp.round_id, 'predicted_frequency', temp.round_number, temp.day_of_production
FROM round_data_temperature AS temp 
    INNER JOIN round_data_humidity AS hum 
        ON temp.round_number = hum.round_number 
           AND temp.x = hum.x 
           AND temp.y = hum.y AND DATE_FORMAT(temp.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(hum.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
    INNER JOIN round_data_airspeed AS airspeed 
        ON temp.round_number = airspeed.round_number 
            AND temp.x = airspeed.x AND temp.y = airspeed.y 
            AND DATE_FORMAT(temp.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(airspeed.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
WHERE temp.round_id ='xxxxx'
```

This code runs very fast on just mysql but is very slow and times out in mysql-connector in python with 20k plus rows so I decided to insert immediately to avoid selecting very large packets of data in python. I did the below:

```
INSERT INTO round_data_pf (value, time, x, y, z, round_id, observable_name, round_number, day_of_production)
SELECT
        ROUND(311.30004 - (20.110938 * temp.value) 
        - (2.012626 * hum.value) - (2.006346 * airspeed.value) 
        + (0.4059 * POWER(temp.value, 2) + (0.006604 * POWER(hum.value, 2)) 
        + (3.151145 * POWER(airspeed.value, 2) + (0.05555 * temp.value * hum.value) 
        - (0.37037 * temp.value * airspeed.value) + (0.03968 * hum.value * airspeed.value))), 2) 
        AS value, temp.time, temp.x, temp.y, temp.z, temp.round_id, 'pf', temp.round_number, temp.day_of_production
FROM round_data_temperature AS temp 
    INNER JOIN round_data_humidity AS hum 
        ON temp.round_number = hum.round_number 
            AND temp.x = hum.x 
            AND temp.y = hum.y 
            AND DATE_FORMAT(temp.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(hum.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
    INNER JOIN round_data_airspeed AS airspeed 
        ON temp.round_number = airspeed.round_number 
            AND temp.x = airspeed.x 
            AND temp.y = airspeed.y 
            AND DATE_FORMAT(temp.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(airspeed.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')
WHERE temp.round_id ='xxxxx'
```

This code times out in both mysql and mysql-connector in python when I have about 20k rows of data.

I am looking to optimize the code so it selects and inserts faster when I have say 20k plus rows.

Comment: No very clear in your question,is it fast in mysql as compared to slow in python on the SAME amount of data?

Comment: In mysql without the insert it executes in less than 2 seconds with about 20k row of data. With the insert, it times out. In python it times out in both cases with about 20k row of data.

Comment: 20K rows is a tiny amount of data. If the query is slow it means there are missing indexes, or that the query *prevents* the server from using any indexes. The server may have to scan the entire table just to get those 100 or 20K rows

Comment: It also depends on the distribution of data - how many rows it returns from ALL the rows? IF more than 35% or so the optimizer will prefer a table scan no matter what indexes you have.

Comment: That `DATE_FORMAT(temp.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') = DATE_FORMAT(airspeed.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')` prevents the server from using indexes on either `time` column. That's because the indexes use the original values, not the formatted strings that this query wants to compare. This means that the server will have to format and compare all the rows produced by the other join conditions

Comment: @Mihai with that `DATE_FORMAT` the server won't be able to select what could be a very selective index

Comment: I have them indexed apart from time. I will index time now. The answer below suggests a composite index. Not sure if that differs from doing `KEY `coordinates` (`x`, `y`, `z`, `observable_name`)` for example which is what I did when creating the tables.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos True,missed that.

Comment: @J.Ewa you need to fix the query, not just index time. Why do you use `DATE_FORMAT` instead of comparing the values? You want to join by times, not *strings*. Furthermore, that conditions will produce the *cartesian product* of any records in that period.

Comment: If I don't use the timestamps to compare and use say the round_number, the joins will match multiple x and y coordinates with the same round_number. I had to add that to take away this issue. Additionally, potential matching values might differ slightly by seconds but are definitely equal by minutes. That is why I round down to minutes.

Comment: @J.Ewa what you did now is round to the hour and produce the *cartesian product* of the records in that minute, with a query that doesn't allow any indexing. If you had 10 measurements in each table for that minute, you'll get 100 items out that query. The way that's calculated though is by fully scanning each table - for each minute

Comment: @J.Ewa the way such problems are typically solved is by using a Calendar and/or Time table that contain dates with extra columns for year, month, day etc, for eg 20 years in the future, and all time values in the resolution you want, with extra coluns for hour, minute etc. There are 86400 seconds in a day, so a time table with such detail won't be big. You can join with these tables on the date/time key and filter or group by using the *extra* columns.

Comment: I will rewrite the query so that I can drop the DATE_FORMAT function, use only columns that I have indexed and see if it speeds things up.

Comment: I have removed the the DATE_FORMAT from the query tried it on a small sample of about 100 rows, it executes very fast. When I increase the number of rows, it becomes very very slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191298/discussion-between-j-ewa-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have proper index  on

```
table round_data_temperature composite index  on columns (round_id, round_number, x, y,  time)

table  round_data_humidity     composite index  on columns (round_number, x, y time) 

table  round_data_airspeed   comoosite index on clumns (round_number, x, y,time   )
```

You must considere the fact that each table involved  in relation can use only one index ..  if you have not index on a table the table is full scanned.

The difference between a single column index  and a composite index  is that  all the column (left  to right) present in the index  are used  for filter  the query avoiding the access to the table data so in certain situation the use of composite index  (properly defined )  can improved  the query in a significant way  ..

Comment: I did index my rows but not as composite aside from time. I will index time now but is there a difference between the a normal index and a composite index? If so, I will make them composite indexes.

Comment: @J.Ewa the query can't use any indexes on time the way it's written. If you have no indexes, the query fully scans both tables

Comment: @J.Ewa  . i have posted  some suggetions for index ..  answer  updated .. if you have not  index or not have a valid  selective left to right index ..the access to the table data can produce relevant effect on performance